# multiple queries in a transaction and committing/rolling back with php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Lets say I have these three mysql queries:

```
SELECT customer_id FROM customers WHERE name = 'John'
INSERT INTO quests_on (quest_id, name, quest_points) VALUES ('1', 'John', '15)
UPDATE badges_on SET badge_owned = 'owned' WHERE quest_id = '1'
```

How would I use a mysql transaction to ensure that all changes are made else rollback the changes. Would using the PDO extension in php suffice here? Just needed some clarity. I was also wondering if you could have SELECT queries in a transaction and that if transactions can take different paths (such as if the value from the SELECT query exists or not)

Comment: Also you need to use innodb engine in mysql that supports transactions.

Answer (score 2):

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$db->beginTransaction();
try {
  // do your queries here, using PDO and $db object
  $db->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  $db->rollback();
}
```

For more information, please read http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: ok, but does this mean I can have conditions that within this transaction, like if there are no results in a SELECT query, run this INSERT query

Comment: @PraneetSharma Why not? You're using PHP already. You can test results of any query and change program flow.